Seding Pose with rotational freedom around the roll axis
as stated in the title, what I'm looking to do is send a Pose command via MoveIt using the move group interface. The Position should be defined, and the Orientation should only be defined around the pitch and yaw axis, while leaving the roll axis. So ideally the IK should find the best solution with consideration of all possible Roll orientations.
Is something like that possible?
